# Force man to output ANSI codes

Tags: travis-ci, manpage, ansi-escape, groff

I'm using `man` along with `man2html` to automatically generate some html documentation, along the lines of `man manpage | man2html`. This is working well, except when I run it on Travis CI, `man` is not generating the proper escape sequences to make headers and options bold. Is there a way to force `man` to generate these codes?

I also took a look at using `groffer --mode=tty` instead of `man`, which works on my Mac, but on Linux (i.e., Travis CI), instead of generating the binary ANSI codes that `man2html` can read, it generates plain-text codes, like `[1m`.

Answer (score 4):

There is some missing information, but I will attempt to fill it in:

- there is more than one program named `man2html`.  I believe you are referring to the Perl script, which I also use.  (I have made some improvements which you can find on my [scripts page](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#others_scripts), but that does not alter the issue).
- by comparison, there is another program (see manual page), which expects to format the manpage itself - unlike the Perl script.
- a while back, one of the developers working with `groff` added a (mis)feature, changing the default behavior of `nroff` to product *escape sequences* for colors.  Those would be something like `^[[34m` or `^[[1m`, for color or bold text.
- aside from that, everyone else's `nroff` produced not *escape sequences*` but *backspace-sequences*, using overstriking to simulate underlining or bold text (_^HXX^HX for example).
- not everyone like the `groff` feature (see for instance this [mailing list comment](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-35047-start-0.html)).
- the `groff` feature can be overridden by setting the environment variable `GROFF_NO_SGR`, as noted in the manual page for [`grotty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grotty).

Beyond the problem with *escape sequences* versus *backspace sequences*, `groff` may generate UTF-8 if you are using a locale whose encoding is UTF-8.  There are a few places where this is noticeable:

- hyphenation
- special characters, such as © (copyright)
- tables

The `man2html` script does not know anything about multibyte encodings such as UTF-8, and will do unexpected things.  As a workaround, overriding the locale settings to POSIX fixes the problem, by setting these environment variables:

```
LANG=C
LC_ALL=C
LC_CTYPE=C
LANGUAGE=C
```

Comment: `GROFF_NO_SGR` seems to work well with `groffer --mode=tty`, except I end up with `\xe2\x80\x90` where there are hyphenations, which leads to issues with man2html.

Comment: I'm also curious what your improvements to man2html are. I didn't see a changelog or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I use this environment variable in my code, to generate overtyping codes from man, for non interactive shell:

```
export MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1
```

The answer was on here [How to run man with formatting in not interactive shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118705/how-to-run-man-with-formatting-in-not-interactive-shell)